# Chrome: Shortcut to Add current URL to specific bookmarks folder

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How can i define a keyboard shortcut so that the current tab's URL will be added to a specific bookmarks folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl + D to bookmark the current site.

Ctrl + Shift + D bookmarks all open tabs into a new folder